# Override custom keyboard shortcut limit

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, shortcuts

I would like to add a custom keyboard shortcut for the "Home" button, but I get the error:

> The shortcut "Home" cannot be used because it will become impossible to type using this key.

I am using this system for a kiosk and will have no other need for the Home button other than for triggering a script. Is there any way to override this limit? Using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Please try add mapping to Home through xmodmap:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap

Comment: I played around a bit with that. While I can remap the Home key to something else, it seems that I still can't use the Home key by itself as a custom shortcut.

Comment: Hmmm I found another option, please try xbindkeys:
 

It looks simpler:  ~/.xbindkeysrc would look something like

"myscript"
    Control + Alt + F7